# iPhone Display icon in Mail attachement forward actionsheet

Tags: iphone, ios

How to show application icon in mail document forward actionsheet as shown below.

Description :

1. Any Document in Mail attachement.
2. Press and hold until you see action sheet like below image.

Please help me to show my application icon in this action sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear.

Probably you are looking for [**UIDocumentInteractionController**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

`UIDocumentInteractionController` allows your app to integrate with documents of specified format.

Check these tutorials :

- [Previewing Documents](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/previewing-and-opening-documents-with-uidocumentinteractioncontroller/)
- [Sharing Data](http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/)
- [Import/Export Documents](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/importing-exporting-documents-ios)

Comment: Thanks Midhun for reply, what i want is when i have document in mail app, and i click and hold it should show me my application icon so, that i can get that file in my application.

Comment: @iOSDev: My guess was correct !!! :) Please check the 3rd [tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/importing-exporting-documents-ios), it'll help you to do that. That tutorials explain step by step implementation.

Comment: Check this : http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/importing-exporting-documents-ios

Comment: But this is from our applications only, what i want when mail application has attachment and click and hold on that attachment it should display my application icon.

Comment: What ever you are telling is to send our application files to other applications on to iPhone.

Comment: @iOSDev: No, I think you didn't checked the last [tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/importing-exporting-documents-ios). If yes then check the statement above the *Figure 14. Your application is capable of handling PDF document* of that tutorial. In which he is using email application and holding the pdf to display his own application. Please check it... I done it before using that tutorial. This tutorial is also can be found on `Wei Meng Lee`'s iOS 5 programming Text.

Comment: @iOSDev: do you still have the issue ?

Comment: Thanks Midhun. It helps me lot, I missed to scroll down to Import section of that link.

Answer (score 0):

You want to register your application for the file types you are able to receive.  Documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

> To declare its support for file types, your app must include the CFBundleDocumentTypes key in its Info.plist property list file. (See “Core Foundation Keys”.) The system adds this information to a registry that other apps can access through a document interaction controller.